# What does it mean by `incompatible block pointer assigning to....'?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, block

I use QuickDialog in my project, I upgrade their library, but I got many errors like that:

`incompatible block pointer assigning to....`?

Here is one of the example:

`elType.onValueChanged = ^(void){[self eventTypeChanged:nil];};`

It works fine before, but after I update the library, it shows: 
`Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'void (^) (QRootElement *__strong)' from 'void' (^)(void)'`

What does this error message means? And how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: The block definition has changed.  Check the docs/header file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that the block that is being passed in does not have a matching signature to the one that the method expects.

In this case, `elType.onValueChanged` expects a block that takes a `QRootElement *__strong` parameter and returns `void`. The block you are passing in takes `void` and returns `void` and so is incompatible.

I would check the library documentation for information on block changes.